# train() function in r - SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I'm running a SVM in R with caret package. My entire df (named `total`, which includes train and test) are scaled numbers from 0 to 1. My Y is binary (0-1). All the variables have the class "num". Here is the code:

```
model_SVM <- train(
  Y ~ ., training,
  method = "svmPoly",
  trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv", number = 10,
    verboseIter = TRUE
  )
)

summary(model_SVM) 
model_SVM

SVMprediction <-predict(model_SVM, testing)
cmSVM <-confusionMatrix(SVMprediction,testing$Y) # ERROR
print(SVMprediction)
```

I got this error1 in the line `# ERROR`

```
> cmSVM <-confusionMatrix(SVMprediction,testing$Y)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

It was solved by adding:

```
SVMprediction<-as.factor(SVMprediction)
testing$Y<-as.factor(testing$Y)
```

However, I got an error2 now in `# ERROR2`:

```
Error in confusionMatrix.default(SVMprediction, testing$Y) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

When I check the levels, `SVMprediction` has 361 levels, and `testing$Y` 2 levels. How `SVMprediction` got 361 levels if the Y had just two?

Thanks!

PS: The full code:

```
totalY <- total

total <- total%>%
  select(-Y)

# Missing Values with MICE
mod_mice <- mice(data = total, m = 5,meth='cart')
total <- complete(mod_mice)
post_mv_var_top10 <- total


Y <- totalY$Y
total<-cbind(total,Y)


train_ <- total%>%
  filter(is.na(Y)==FALSE)

test_ <- total%>%
  filter(is.na(Y)==TRUE)


inTraining <- createDataPartition(train_$Y, p = .70, list = FALSE)
training <- train_[ inTraining,]
testing  <- train_[-inTraining,]


# MODEL SVM

model_SVM <- train(
  Y ~ ., training,
  method = "svmPoly",
  trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv", number = 10,
    verboseIter = TRUE
  )
)

summary(model_SVM)

SVMprediction <-predict(model_SVM, testing)

SVMprediction<-as.factor(SVMprediction)
testing$Y<-as.factor(testing$Y)

cmSVM <-confusionMatrix(SVMprediction,testing$Y) # ERROR 2
print(cmSVM)
```

Comment: documentation of `confusionMatrix` data: a factor of predicted classes, reference: a factor of classes to be used as the true results. So yes, factorize just before you call confusionMatrix.

Comment: @phiver It seems that the problem is the number of levels of the 'SVMprediction'. I put the whole code, but I don't understand how 'SVMprediction' got so many levels with an Y with just two levels.

Comment: Check if you get 0 and 1 out of your prediction or the probabilities of the prediction. That is often an issue

Comment: `caret`, and most R classification models, assume that your outcome vector is a factor. Passing it binary numeric data makes it do regression and it doesn't generate a predicted class. Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered definitively.